# What are the default DataAnnotations for IdentityUser's UserName property?

Tags: asp.net-identity

What are the default `DataAnnotations` for `IdentityUser`'s `UserName` property? I can't find them.

I want to know, because i want to override the property to add more `DataAnnotations` to the property, but when overridden all old `DataAnnotations` will be lost. I need to know which ones they are to add them to the overridden property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no data-annotations on `Username` in the default framework implementation:

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
    where TLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public IdentityUser()
    {
        Claims = new List<TClaim>();
        Roles = new List<TRole>();
        Logins = new List<TLogin>();
    }

    /// SNIP


    /// <summary>
    ///     User ID (Primary Key)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     User name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the source code: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUser.cs